# Rearranging an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a row array as shown below:

```
X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 X3 Y3 Z3 X4 Y4 Z4 ..... Xn Yn Zn
```

This row array always starts with the value of `X`  and with the value of `Z`. I want to rearrange them as a multidimensional array:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 .... Xn
Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 .... Yn
Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4 Z5 .... Zn
```

The size of the original array varies in each case. Any help to how to approach this problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reshape` function setting second dimension as `[]`

```
reshaped_array = reshape(myarray,3,[]);
```